# PHP permissions after file copy

Tags: php, permissions, copy

I have a problem here for hours that I cannot figure out. I have a script that uploads pictures to a server. I also offer the possibility to erase pictures from the uploaded ones. This is working fine.

However, the user may want to 'publish' these pictures. When he does, they are copied to a new folder. If he wants to edit his gallery pictures are copied back to a temporal folder. After this happens, the files cannot be erased anymore, PHP doesn't want to. I checked the permissions and they are the same, and I'm also obtaining the owner of the file via fileowner() and it's the same owner both when the pictures can be erased and when they can't... Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? Are the permissions on the folders the same, as well as on the files? Are all the folders inside your web root? What PHP function are you using to copy the files?

Comment: What permissions are you using (i.e. 755)?

Comment: 777, Linux, permissions are 777 for folders and files. They are all inside web root, I am using this function to copy recursively: http://www.visible-form.com/blog/copy-directory-in-php/

Comment: When you call `is_writable()` on the files, do you get the same result in both folders? On the command line, does the output of `ls -l` match exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are working with the pictures, are you making sure to close the file handle and/or the directory handle? If not, try doing that and then see if the pictures can be deleted.

[fclose function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

[closedir function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php)

Comment: not really opening any handles... I think that my first copy is copying the files with really strict permissions, like 411... I still don't know why though. You could revise the algorithm I use to copy: visible-form.com/blog/copy-directory-in-php

Comment: I took a quick look at it. PHP's documentation says to avoid using umask() in multithreaded webservers. Maybe you should use chmod() instead? http://us3.php.net/umask

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at [clearstatcache()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) I think this will solve your problem.

> This function caches information about specific filenames, so you only need to call clearstatcache() if you are performing multiple operations on the same filename and require the information about that particular file to not be cached.

Have a look at the example in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php), it clearly shows the problem with ownership for instance.